# Accessing git submodule in Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio, git-submodules

I'm just starting out using source control for my own project, and now I want to add Joda-Time. I want to add it as a submodule so I went into the terminal and executed:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time.git
```

and it downloaded all the files successfully. Then I ran:

```
git submodule init
```

And got nothing back.

```
git submodule status
```

returns

```
b9fe534c7f5876eced6494a6d6c1deaf2528a579 joda-time (v2.7-17-gb9fe534)
```

I checked my projects root directory and I see the new joda-time directory and it's source. But now how do I access the library in my project? Did I miss a step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to have any luck with the answers provided. As I kept searching the internet for a hint of help I stumbled across [Joda-Time-Android](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android) so I removed the original Joda-Time submodule and tried again with the new. It works! It added itself to my project and it's ready to rock!

During the time I was still troubleshooting the original issue Joda-Time doesn't include a build.gradle file but Joda-Time-Android does - I think that was the problem.

Comment: Good job. I think now I understand your original question. Don't forget to accept your own answer :-)

Comment: I think your problem was that you did not set the module as a dependency in your gradle-file. "It added itself to my project" well yeah, because you added it as a dependency now -> `dependencies {  implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.10.3'}`.

Answer (score 5):

Try with `git submodule update --init`. This will allow you to do `git submodule init` and `git submodule update` in one step. Note that you only need to add the `--init` option once.

Quoting from the [doc](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule):

> **update**
>
> Update the registered submodules to match what the superproject
>   expects by cloning missing submodules and updating the working
>   tree of the submodules.

On the other hand, `git init` by itself simply

> copying submodule names and urls from [your] .gitmodules [file] to [your local] .git/config [folder].

Once you did this, you will notice that your submodule is in a DETACHED state. You can simply checkout any existing branch from there, say, `git checkout master` to checkout upstream `master` branch.

Answer (score 2):

You missed `git submodule update`. From the docs:

> Update the registered submodules to match what the superproject
>   expects by cloning missing submodules and updating the working tree of
>   the submodules.

You can also do it with the `--init` option, which will do the `git submodule init` for you.